# How to move inline radio inputs under label,

Tags: html, css, forms, label

So Im a complete beginner and Im stuck on some personal project. Im making forms and I want to have inputs from radio buttons all in the same line, but under the label. I know how to make all elements inline and I know that setting the block property should put them under label. But block element puts all of the inputs on its on line. What I want is all inputs to be on the same line, under lable. I can use 
 tag in HTML, but I want to make it with CSS. Any tips?

```
                <div class="radio" >
                 <label class="radio" for="age">Your age:</label>
                 <input type="radio" name="age">0-20
                 <input type="radio" name="age">20-40
                 <input type="radio" name="age">40-60
                 <input type="radio" name="age">60-80
                 <input type="radio" name="age">80-100
                </div>

                <div class="radio" >
                 <label class="radio" for="gender">Your gender</label>
                 <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
                 <input type="radio" name="gender">Female
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put a line break `<br />`

```
<div class="radio" >
      <label class="radio" for="age">Your age:</label>
       <br />
       <input type="radio" name="age">0-20
       <input type="radio" name="age">20-40
       <input type="radio" name="age">40-60
       <input type="radio" name="age">60-80
       <input type="radio" name="age">80-100
       </div>

       <div class="radio" >
       <label class="radio" for="gender">Your gender</label>
       <br />
       <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
       <input type="radio" name="gender">Female
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the label to `display: flex;` but make sure not to target the radio class or it will also effect the parent div and not work properly.

Comment: Flexbox is a bit overkill here.  Just setting the label (and avoiding the inputs) to block will do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting all of the radio buttons to `display: block`, setting just the label to `display: block` will get the effect you want.  Block elements will start a new line (if needed) and force the next element to a new line as well.  Since you want just the label to be on a new line by itself, setting it to `display: block` will do the trick.

```css
label.radio {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio" for="age">Your age:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="age">0-20
    <input type="radio" name="age">20-40
    <input type="radio" name="age">40-60
    <input type="radio" name="age">60-80
    <input type="radio" name="age">80-100
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio" for="gender">Your gender</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender">Female
</div>
```